# AuthConfiguration getSamlSsoUrl method return link doesn't work

Tags: single-sign-on, authentication, configuration, saml

So I have the method getSamlSsoUrl(communityUrl, startURL, samlId) from the class AuthConfiguration and returned a very long url with saml id, saml acs, saml binding type, and etc in the url.

However, when I go to the link, it returned an invalid page in my community.  Do I have to set something up before immediately calling this method?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthConfiguration.htm

Comment: Are you passing something in the `startURL` parameter? I suspect that could be the problem.

Comment: Yes I'm passing a startURL which is just the community home url

Comment: If you leave that null, can you see if the link you generate works?

Comment: I tried both with the startURL and with null

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the same issue: the URL seems to be ok, but the it doesn't performs the login correctly and reedirects to the maintenance page of the community.

Finnally, I got it fixed up just by setting an empty string in place of startURL:

String sso = Auth.AuthConfiguration.getSamlSsoUrl(communityUrl, '', ssoConfig[0].Id);

Hope it helps.